# Python: list variable used in conditional in indexing another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the name of the technique where there is a conditional is used in an index for a list but the variable in the conditional is a list itself? As you can see `a` is a list but it is used to check for corresponding elements in the list `b`.

```
>>> a = [ 1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [7, 7,7]

>>> b[a==1] = 8

>>> b
[8, 7, 7]
```

I was writing code using numpy arrays and thought of seeing if core Python included the same feature and it turns out it exists. I just had no way of searching for it because I didn't have the slightest idea of what it is called.

EDIT:
I would like to know what is called and also an explanation of what is going on given the comments indicate that the code isn't doing what I think it is doing.

For clarity and elaboration, this is the code that I entered for numpy and got replacement similar to the Python list.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lower_green = np.array([0,180,0]) 
>>> upper_green = np.array([100,255,100])
>>> upper_green[lower_green == 0] = 7
>>> upper_green
array([  7, 255,   7])
```

Comment: Do you want to know what its doing or what its called?

Comment: _"it turns out it exists"_. Are you sure about that? Try `b[a==3] = 9` and see if it has the effect you expect.

Comment: This is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: _This is not the droid you are looking for_ - or your conclusion is faulty ;)

Comment: @myrtlecat, could you explain what is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deconstructing the expression, we get:

1. `(False == 0) == True`
2. `(a == 1) == False`

Given this, we arrive at the conclusion that

```
b[a == 1] == b[False] == b[0]
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't see the logic here and made the wrong conclusion that indexing in python lists worked the same way as numpy indexing.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be achieved as follows (it will not work in all the cases):

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3]
b = [7, 7, 7]
b[a.index(1)] = 8

output:
b = [8, 7, 7]
```

However, the method `index()` returns only the lowest index if there are multiple matching elements. Therefore, it won't work in the following case:

```
a = [0, 1, 1]
b = [7, 7, 7]
b[a.index(1)] = 8

output:
b = [7, 8, 7] and not [7, 8, 8]
```

However, if you want to do it using core Python, here it goes (taking help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45559614/1586200) answer):

```
# first get all the indices of the matching elements

a = [0, 1, 1]
b = [7, 7, 7]
to_match = 1
to_replace = 8

ind = [n for n,x in enumerate(a) if x == to_match]
for i in ind:
    b[i] = to_replace
```

Answer (score 1):

`a==1` is false, which is the same as zero

it's not the same as using an array of booleans in numpy[1]. (sometimes called logical indexing)

[1]
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html